# sub-sum from a list without loops

Tags: python, recursion

So i'm studying recursion and have to write some codes using **no loops**

For a part of my code I want to check if I can sum up a subset of a list to a specific number, and if so return the indexes of those numbers on the list.

For example, if the list is [5,40,20,20,20] and i send it with the number 60, i want my output to be [1,2] since 40+20=60.
In case I can't get to the number, the output should be an empty list.

I started with

```
def find_sum(num,lst,i,sub_lst_sum,index_lst):  
if num == sub_lst_sum:
    return index_lst
if i == len(sum): ## finished going over the list without getting to the sum
    return []
if sub_lst_sum+lst[i] > num:
    return find_sum(num,lst,i+1,sub_lst_sum,index_lst)
return ?..

index_lst = find_sum(60,[5,40,20,20,20],0,0,[])
```

*num* is the number i want to sum up to,

*lst* is the list of numbers

the last return should go over both the option that I count the current number in the list and not counting it.. (otherwise in the example it will take the five and there will be no solution).
I'm not sure how to do this..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint. Perhaps the simplest way to go about it is to consider the following inductive reasoning to guide your recursion.

If

```
index_list = find_sum(num,lst,i+1)
```

Then

```
index_list = find_sum(num,lst,i)
```

That is, if a list of indices can be use to construct a sum `num` using elements from position `i+1` onwards, then it is also a solution when using elements from position `i` onwards. That much should be clear. The second piece of inductive reasoning is,

If

```
index_list = find_sum(num-lst[i],lst,i+1)
```

Then

```
[i]+index_list = find_sum(num,lst,i)
```

That is, if a list of indices can be used to return a sum `num-lst[i]` using elements from position `i+1` onwards, then you can use it to build a list of indices whose respective elements sum is `num` by appending `i`.

These two bits of inductive reasoning can be translated into two recursive calls to solve the problem. Also the first one I wrote should be used for the second recursive call and not the first (question: why?).

Also you might want to rethink using empty list for the base case where there is no solution. That can work, but your returning as a solution a list that is not a solution. In python I think `None` would be a the standard idiomatic choice (but you might want to double check that with someone more well-versed in python than me).

---

Fill in the blanks

```
def find_sum(num,lst,i):  
    if num == 0  :
        return []
    elif i == len(lst) :
        return None 
    else :
        ixs = find_sum(???,lst,i+1)
        if ixs != None :
            return ???
        else :
            return find_sum(???,lst,i+1)
```

Comment: I think i get your idea but i'm not sure how to execute it..
Every number from the list that i'm "counting" I should subtract from `num` and stop when `num == 0`
But what am i returning then? how do i keep track of the indexes?

Comment: That's one of the two recursion paths. Given `lst` and `num` at index `i` you can either try to find a solution that includes the element `lst[i]` and solution that doesn't include it. For a solution that includes `lst[i]`, you do make a recursive call with `num-lst[i]`. For a solution that doesn't include `lst[i]`, you will proceed with `num`. Yes, when you reach `0` then you would return an empty list as the solution (which is why I said you should use something else for failure). Returning `0` for the sum of no elements is in line with the mathematical convention.

Comment: Regarding "keeping track of indices", you can but don't need to. Just use the indices returned by the recursive call (either some valid list, or `None`) at each step. Note there's "two ways" to do recursion, you could do a factorial like this (pseudocode): `fact(ac,n) = if n == 0 then  ac else  fact(ac*n,n-1)` where you "keep track" of the multiplied terms, or like this `fact(n) = if n == 0 then  1 else n*fact(n-1)` where you don't "keep track", rather at each step you use the result of the recursive call.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide some code, just left some blanks for you to fill in.